# To place one of the list item in week day in the center of the screen on that particular day

Tags: flutter, listview

I wants to display the particular item from `LIST` at the center of the screen

I have `LIST` of `WIDGET` of week day 
i.e.
sunday
monday
tuesday
...
Like today day is Friday then `FRIDAY` `WIDGET` appear in the middle of screen automatically and on next day `SUNDAY` `WIDGET` comes in the middle of screen 
[image of the list widget that  look alike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftlmQ.png)

'''

```
 @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          // itemCount: 7,

          itemCount: dayList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [

                    Expanded(
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage("${dayList[index].iconSrc}"),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Text(
                      'AQI:${dayList[index].aqi}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: dayList[index].color,
                          fontFamily: "MerriWeather"),
                    ),

                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      height: 40,
                      width: 70,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          // 'Mon',
                          dayList[index].day,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'MerriWeather',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ));
          },
        ));
```

'''

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is your end output? It's hard to think about what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Like wanna display particular List item in the center of screen
I am displaying the week day sunday monday tuesday wednesday ... and if wednesday come today then wednesday should lies in the center of the screen on that day and on next day thursday comes on its place i.e. in the center of the screen